# If the field doesnt exist in the document how do i handle the firebase query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am ordering the objects from firebase by timestamp and timestamp was included in last build. How do i handle a case where there is no timestamp it should just push the object to last?
Basically sorting the stuff using timestamp and want to push the queries with no timestamp in the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you perform a query that filters and sorts a collection using a specific field, and that field **does not exist in a document**, that document will not appear in the query results at all.  In that case, there's nothing you can do in the query to include it to the results.  Firestore indexes can't find documents that don't have a field - indexing only works with fields that are present.

If you're querying a collection for all documents, and you want push a document without some field to the bottom of the results, you will have to apply a sort in your client code to reorder the documents as you require.  Firestore will not do that for you.