# In development with Laravel How to retrieve Firestore queries

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using Laravel to create an application that utilizes Firestore.

I would like to extract only the data where a particular field in the collection retrieved from the Firestore is NULL (does not exist),

```
$query->where('FieldName' ,'!=' , NULL)->collection();
```

The above code does not retrieve anything.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to extract only the data where a particular field in the collection retrieved from the Firestore is NULL (does not exist),

Firestore queries are based on finding the document in an index. There is no way to retrieve documents **without** a field, as they're not present in any index on that field.

The common workaround is to add the field to all documents with a marker value (such as `null`), so that they *are* present in the index. If you're looking to backfill a new field on to existing documents, you will have to read all documents (possibly paginating) and add the field (e.g. with the marker value) to each of them.

Also see:

- [How do I get documents where a specific field exists/does not exists in Firebase Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579693/how-do-i-get-documents-where-a-specific-field-exists-does-not-exists-in-firebase)
- [Firestore query of a collection of documents in which some field does not exist does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69963042/firestore-query-of-a-collection-of-documents-in-which-some-field-does-not-exist)
- [If the field doesnt exist in the document how do i handle the firebase query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63742367/if-the-field-doesnt-exist-in-the-document-how-do-i-handle-the-firebase-query)